# Insert Page Break each time a different value occurs

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search, page-break

I am trying to insert a page break above the row that a different value is found in Column D. I found this code that kind of helps as a start. It is searching for a specific word and creating a page break there. But what if the word isnt always defined? Can someone help update this code or provide feedback on how to create a page break when a different value is found?
Example table is below. It should create a page break above each different invoice number in Column D. If a loop would be easier, please help there as well.

```
Sub InsertPageBreakAtDifValue()
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim LR As Integer
 LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For x = 1 To LR
  If Cells(x, 1).Value = "Invoice Total" Then
 ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(x + 1)
  End If
  Next
End Sub
```

| Line | Value | Quantity | Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | 10 | 12345 |
| 20 | 100 | 10 | 12345 |
| 30 | 100 | 10 | 12345 |
| 40 | 100 | 10 | 56789 |
| 50 | 100 | 10 | 56789 |
| 60 | 100 | 10 | 56789 |
| 70 | 100 | 10 | 78910 |

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the data range is sorted by Invoice Number.

```
Dim invNo As Integer
Dim prevInvNo As Integer

prevInvNo = 0
For x = 1 to LR
    invNo = Cells(x, 1).Value
    ' if invoice number has changed...
    if prevInvNo <> invNo then
        ' don't insert a page break before the first invoice number
        if prevInvNo > 0 then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(x + 1)
        end if
        prevInvNo = invNo  
    end if
next x
```